# Angular 5 HTTP Observable GET Request handle nested objects

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, api, angular5

Got a problem with my angular app.

I've created an api with the guidelines from *jsonapi.org* so that my api look's like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "text": "Hello, World!"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "user": {
          "data": {
            "type": "users",
            "id": "1"
          },
          "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost/api/users/1"
          }
        },
        "comments": [

        ]
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost/api/posts/1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost/api/posts?page=1",
    "last": "http://localhost/api/posts?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null,
    "self": "http://localhost/api/posts"
  },
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "path": "http://localhost/api/posts",
    "per_page": 15,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

And now I'm trying to implement the api into my angular 5 app. At the moment I fetch the data like this:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
  getPosts (): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(posts => this.log(`fetched posts`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
      );
  }
```

The problem is now how can I get the objects right? Because angular wants that the objects are as array in the root of the api but mines are under 'data'.

Just found the function 'mergeMap' but it isn't working as expected and so I've still the same problem.

Comment: what `console.log(posts)` in the `tap` block gives you?

Comment: Could you use observables ".map" function and return posts.data

Comment: If you want result.data, you can use map. map transform the result (your object with properties "data","links","meta"..) by as you want: return this.http.get<POST[]>(this.postUrl).pipe(map(result=>{return result.data})

Comment: Hahaha just found it by my self. But thank you anyway! It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return from your service the content of the `data` property, you could just use `map`:

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    this.http.get(this.postsurl)
            .map(resp => resp.json())
            .map(body => body.data);
}
```

If you need to do processing of the elements to convert them into your specific object type, then you could also do that within the map function.